# Java8 filter arraylist with custom object on field date

Tags: arraylist, java-8, java-stream, simpledateformat, java-time

I have to filter `List<Card>` on the field, `issueDate`(type `String`), where cards to be shown till last 7 years date.

The solution that I've tried is to parse `issueDate` field from `String` to `Date` and then apply `date.after(startDate)` and `date.before(endDate)` as below:

```java
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
cardList.stream()
        .map(s->s.getIssueDate())
        .filter(dt -> sdf.parse(dt).after(sdf.parse("2020-06-08")) && 
                      sdf.parse(dt).before(sdf.parse("2020-08-12")))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Even can't apply for loop as there can be hundreds of cards issued, and it impacts performance by iterating on each card issue date(string to date and check year)

Can anyone suggest a good solution to this problem?

Comment: I don't understand. [Streams](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) were added in Java 8, so why did you tag your question `java-7`? And since you are using Java 8, use the classes in [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html) package to parse the string, rather than class `SimpleDateFormat`.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDate` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Iterating several hundred cards doesn’t take long. No matter if using a `for` loop or some other means.

Answer (score 5):

There are many problems with your code:

1. The `java.util` date-time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)<sup>*</sup> .
2. You should declare `issueDate` as `LocalDate` (or `Date` if you still want to stick to the legacy API) instead of `String`. However, for any reason, if you still want to keep it as `String`, you can change your code to parse it to a date-type object only once during Stream processing (currently, you are doing it twice).
3. You are parsing `2020-06-08` and `2020-08-12` inside Stream processing whereas they are static values and therefore they should be parsed outside the Stream processing. In fact, if these static dates are not as `String`, you can create date-type objects directly e.g. `LocalDate start = LocalDate.of(2020, 6, 8)`.

These suggestions have been incorporated in the following code:

```
LocalDate start = LocalDate.parse("2020-06-08");
LocalDate end = LocalDate.parse("2020-08-12");

List<LocalDate> dates = 
        cardList.stream()
                .map(card -> LocalDate.parse(card.getIssueDate()))
                .filter(ld -> ld.isAfter(start) && ld.isBefore(end))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If you want to collect the Stream into a list of cards, you can do it as follows:

```
List<Card> cards = 
        cardList.stream()
                .filter(card -> {
                    LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse(card.getIssueDate());                            
                    return ld.isAfter(start) && ld.isBefore(end);
                })
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project). Learn more about the modern date-time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you need to parse the dates here. All of your dates are `String` and have the same `yyyy-MM-dd` format.

In this particular case you could simply compare the strings lexicographically:

```java
String from = "2020-06-08";
String to = "2020-08-12";

List<Card> filteredCardList = 
    cardList.stream()
            .filter(card -> card.getIssueDate().compareTo(from) > 0)
            .filter(card -> card.getIssueDate().compareTo(to) < 0)
            .collect(toList());
```

or you do the same with plain old loop:

```java
List<Card> filteredCardList = new ArrayList<>();
for(Card card : cardList) {
    String date = card.getIssueDate();
    if(date.compareTo(from) > 0 && date.compareTo(to) < 0) {
        filteredCardList.add(card);
    }
}
```